# How to call method with View Parameter in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, methods, view, android-actionbar

How can i call this method `Calculate()` from the menu in the actionbar?

The application objective is to calculate the following formula: `A = (2X + F) / (X - 2F)` Here is my java code

```
  {
    private EditText txtX;
    private EditText txtF;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtX=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.X);
        txtF=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.F);
    }

    public void Calculate() {
        boolean ok = true;
        double x = 0;

        try {
            x = leeDouble(txtX);

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            ok = false;
        }
        double f = 0;
        try {
            f = leeDouble(txtF);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            ok = false;
        }

        if (ok) {
            final double divisor = x - 2 * f;
            if (Math.abs(divisor) > 0.0005) {
                double a = (2 * x + f) / divisor;
                message("a=" + a);
            } else {
                message("Wrong numbers");
            }
        }
    }
        private void message(String texto){
            Toast.makeText(this,texto,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private double leeDouble(EditText editText) throws NumberFormatException{
        try{
            return Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString().trim());
        } catch(NumberFormatException e){
            editText.setError("Wrong number");
            throw e;
        }  }
```

With this action in the menu xml file

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_calculate"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/text2"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />
```

when i try to call it it says it need one parameter.

Comment: I have edited your question, you don´t need the "Vista" paremeter

Comment: I need help with my code, can i show it to you so you can help me?

Comment: sure, post your code to help you.

Comment: I have posted the complete code in my answer, just be sure to have the value of "text2" defined into your Strings.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the method `onOptionsItemSelected()`

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_calculate) {
            Calculate();  //Execute the method!
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

but you don´t need the argument:

```
public void Calculate() {
...
```

if you want execute the method from a View, then you need the argument View, for example:

```
public void Calculate(View Vista) {
....
```

executing the method from a Button, use the property `android:onClick`

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/myButton"
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Click me!"
android:onClick="Calcula"/>
```

#### Update:

This is the complete code:

```
    private EditText txtX;
    private EditText txtF;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtX=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.X);
        txtF=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.F);
    }


    public void Calculate() {
        boolean ok = true;
        double x = 0;

        try {
            x = leeDouble(txtX);

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            ok = false;
        }
        double f = 0;
        try {
            f = leeDouble(txtF);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            ok = false;
        }

        if (ok) {
            final double divisor = x - 2 * f;
            if (Math.abs(divisor) > 0.0005) {
                double a = (2 * x + f) / divisor;
                message("a=" + a);
            } else {
                message("Wrong numbers");
            }
        }
    }
    private void message(String texto){
        Toast.makeText(this,texto,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private double leeDouble(EditText editText) throws NumberFormatException{
        try{
            return Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString().trim());
        } catch(NumberFormatException e){
            editText.setError("Wrong number");
            throw e;
        }  }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_calculate) {
            Calculate();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am deeply sorry for being so annoying, im new at this.
There must be a logical error in this code, when you hit the action the application stops, all the link between layout and java is ok, the problem is with that method.
I can send you my project if its Ok to you, i would seriously appreciate help

Comment: to see what happens post the error message displayed on your LogCat, must be something easy to fix. Ok paste a link of your project.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8DN1S9kFdPgcjI0VmtHb1BDYkk/view?usp=sharing
Theres the project, hum sorry for the spanish gimme a min and i can post the logcat error message

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/tTZHs.png cant post images, but there it is some problem in the validation leeDouble

Comment: SOLVED IT, thanks for all the patience that u had on me, you helped me a lot Have a nice day!!!